# How resource manager allocate container to the submitted job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

In hadoop 1.X we had several fix size jvms on each node. In the new version we have containers, which will be create if needed.

I want to know that resource manager create containers on which parameters of submitted job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on documentation, YARN is designed to allow individual applications (via the ApplicationMaster) to utilize cluster resources in a shared, secure and multi-tenant manner. Also, it remains aware of cluster topology in order to efficiently schedule and optimize data access i.e. reduce data motion for applications to the extent possible.

In order to meet those goals, the central Scheduler (in the ResourceManager) has extensive information about an application’s resource needs, which allows it to make better scheduling decisions across all applications in the cluster. This leads us to the ResourceRequest and the resulting Container.

Essentially an application can ask for specific resource requests via the ApplicationMaster to satisfy its resource needs. The Scheduler responds to a resource request by granting a container, which satisfies the requirements laid out by the ApplicationMaster in the initial ResourceRequest.

As you may know, we have three scheduling methods in YARN:

- Fair Scheduler
- Capacity Scheduler
- FIFO Scheduler

Each of them has its own ways to calculate applications resource need.

For example, CapacityScheduler has the concept of a ResourceCalculator – a pluggable layer that is used for carrying out the math of allocations by looking at all the identified resources. This includes utilities to help make the following decisions:

- Does this node have enough resources of each resource-type to satisfy this request?
- How many containers can I fit on this node, sorting a list of nodes with varying resources available.
  There are two kinds of calculators currently available in YARN – the DefaultResourceCalculator and the DominantResourceCalculator.

The DefaultResourceCalculator only takes memory into account when doing its calculations. This is why CPU requirements are ignored when carrying out allocations in the CapacityScheduler by default. All the math of allocations is reduced to just examining the memory required by resource-requests and the memory available on the node that is being looked at during a specific scheduling-cycle.

Comment: so,you mean that each schedulers has its Priorities,sometimes CPU is important or sometimes memory,?

what happens when tasks are finished? are containers still there?

Comment: @mndn Yes but both of them are important. Container is a two-dimentional space consists of both CPU and memory. Priority will be calculated by scheduler and passed to the ResourceRequest. When tasks finish, the containers will be removed.

Comment: thanks for your help.My last question is how scheduler estimate  the amount of resources ?Do they use historical information ?

Comment: Not exactly, Each jobs have to say about their needs. A job have to trigger a ResourceRequest with a few parameters like Priority, Capablity and so on. CreateContainer method is like this: `container = createContainer(app, node, capability, priority);`